# Cracking the Coding Interview - 4.1 Graph Traversal

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph

I'm working through the classic *Cracking the Coding Interview* book. I'm trying to solve the following graph problem:

> 4.1) Route Between Nodes: Given a directed graph, design an algorithm to find out whether there is a route between two nodes.

I've written a solution in JavaScript and found it was a lot less complicated than the book's solution. Am I missing something? Why does the solution use a `Visiting` state? Can't we just use `Visited` instead?

```
function RouteBetweenNodes( node1, node2 ) {

    const q = new Queue()
    q.add( node1 )

    while ( !q.isEmpty() ) {
        const node = q.remove()
        if ( node === node2 ) {
            return true 
        }
        node.visited = true
        node.children.forEach( child => !child.visited && q.add( child ) )
    }

    return false 

}
```

Here is an implementation of a `Queue` for completeness:

```
class QueueNode {

    constructor( data ) {
        this.data = data
        this.next = null
    }

}

class Queue {

    constructor() {
        this.first = null
        this.last = null
    }

    add( item ) {
        const newNode = new QueueNode( item )
        if ( this.last ) {
            this.last.next = newNode
        } else {
            this.first = newNode
        }
        this.last = newNode
    }

    remove() {
        if ( this.first ) {
            const data = this.first.data
            this.first = this.first.next
            if ( this.first == null ) {
                this.last == null
            }
            return data
        }
        throw Error( 'empty queue' )
    }

    peek() {
        if ( this.first ) {
            return this.first.data
        }
        throw Error( 'empty queue' )
    }

    isEmpty() {
        return this.first === null 
    }

}
```

[Here is the book's solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HXIx.png)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers =)

Comment: The `Visiting` state lets you tell apart nodes waiting in the queue from the truly uncharted nodes. Without such state the same node may be added multiple times. It hurts performance, and in some (very contrived) cases may even lead to incorrectness.

Comment: @vnp I can't see a case where it would lead to incorrect results. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @hoffmale On a specially crafted infinite graph, with some nodes having infinitely many inbound edges, the algorithm  would fail to find a surely existing path, whereas a book solution would succeed. Pretty contrived, as I said.

Comment: It appears that the code in the image is Java, but your code is Javascript (or at least you used the tag [tag:javascript])... is that intentional?

Comment: JavaScript does not have a `Queue` you will need to include all the code required to run your function and an example or some arguments would save us having to create it by hand.

Comment: @vnp Thanks, that explanation makes sense. With my current implementation the same node could be added to the queue multiple times, which hurts performance.

Comment: @SamOnela I implemented the solution in Javascript to improve my knowledge of the language, in particular, the new class keyword in ecmascript 6.

Comment: Okay- I was going to ask about the queue implementation but I see others have already asked about it and you added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your worst case performance (every node is connected to each other node but `node2`) is \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$, up from the "normal" \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$, because nodes can be added to the queue multiple times. This should also increase the average runtime. **This gets even worse if multiple edges between any 2 nodes are allowed.**

  Note that adding another check `q.contains(node)` would still result in a runtime of \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ as those checks add a factor of \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$. The `Visiting` state prevents this.
- `visited` is never reset to `false` (in the presented code). This will lead to errors in subsequent calls.
- The definition of `Queue` is missing.